# Determining subfields of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_3,\sqrt[3]{2})$ without Galois theory?

Tags: field-theory

Somehow I had convinced myself recently that one could determine the subfields of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_3,\sqrt[3]{2})$ (here $\zeta_3 = \frac{-1+\sqrt{3}i}{2}$ is a primtive $3$rd root of $1$) without using Galois theory, but I'm not so sure any more.

The subfields should be $\mathbb{Q}$, $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_3)$, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$, $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_3\sqrt[3]{2})$, $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_3^2\sqrt[3]{2})$, $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_3,\sqrt[3]{2})$  (corresponding to the subgroups of $\mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_3,\sqrt[3]{2})/\mathbb{Q})\simeq S_3$.

Is there a way to see this without Galois theory or extremely disgusting calculations?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $K$ be a non-trivial subfield of $\Bbb Q(\omega, \root 3 \of 2)$.

Since $[\Bbb Q(\omega, \root 3 \of 2):\Bbb Q\textbf{]}=6$, we have $[K:\Bbb Q\textbf{]}\in\{2,3\}$.

If $[K:\Bbb Q\textbf{]}=2$, then $[\Bbb Q(\omega, \root 3 \of 2):K\textbf{]}=3$ and $\root 3 \of 2 \not \in K$.

Suppose $\omega \not \in K$. It follows that $[K(\omega):\Bbb Q\textbf{]}=4$, which is absurd because $[K(\omega):\Bbb Q\textbf{]}=4$ must divide $[\Bbb Q(\omega, \root 3 \of 2):\Bbb Q\textbf{]}=6$.

Therefore $\omega \in K$. It's easy to conclude that $K=\Bbb Q(\omega )$.

I'm not positive because I didn't check, but I believe the other cases are similar.

**Edit 1:** I don't see how it is similar, so I propose the following argument to conclude:

If $[K:\Bbb Q\textbf{]}=3$, since $[\Bbb Q(\root 3 \of 2):\Bbb Q\textbf{]}=3$, there exists a $\Bbb Q$-isomorphism $\varphi:\Bbb Q(\root 3 \of 2)\to K$.

It is true that $\varphi (\root 3\of 2)$ and $\root 3 \of 2$ share the same minimal polynomial over $\Bbb Q$, because $\varphi$ is a $\Bbb Q$-morphism.

Therefore, since $t^3-2$ is the minimal polynomial of $\root 3\of 2$ over $\Bbb Q$, it comes $\varphi (\root 3 \of 2)\in \{\root 3\of 2,\omega  \root 3\of 2, \omega ^2 \root 3\of 2\}$.

Recall that $\varphi$ ranges in $K$. It follows that $K\in \{\Bbb Q(\root 3\of 2), \Bbb Q(\omega \root 3 \of 2), \Bbb Q(\omega ^2\root 3 \of 2)\}$

**Edit 2:** As suggested by the OP, the case $[K:\Bbb Q\textbf{]}=3$ is in fact similar:

1. If $K$ contains a root of $t^3-2$ then $K$ must be one of the fields we expect it to be.
2. If it doesn't, then $t^3-2$ will be irreducible over $K$ and it's easy to derive a contradiction.

Comment: I don't quite see why your Edit is correct: is it really the case that every extension of degree $3$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$? This can't be.

Comment: Anyway, the case of $[K:\mathbb{Q}]=3$ goes similarly; if $K$ contains a root of $X^3-2$ then we know what $K$ is, but if not then $[K(\sqrt[3]{3}):K]=3$, which is impossible.

Comment: @vgty6h7uij Regarding your first comment see [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/246648/isomorphism-of-two-field-extensions). It should be on any Galois Theory book too. About your second comment I supppose you meant to consider $K(\root \large 3 \of 2)$, but I don't follow why it should be the case that $[K(\root \large 3 \of 2):K\textbf{]}=3$.

Comment: Without using Galois theory I don't see any reason a priori why $K$ should be isomorphic to $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]{2})$. I think vgty6h7uij's argument is correct though. The main point being that if  $K$ does not contain a root of $X^3-2$ then $X^3-2$ is irreducible over $K$.

Comment: I think it's a matter of when does Field Theory become Galois Theory. I wouldn't consider this as using Galois Theory. And of course his reasoning works, I was blind.

Comment: GitGud As written in your Edit1, you can only say that a sub-extension of degree 3 is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$ if you already know that it's generated by a root of $X^3-2$, i.e. assuming what it is we were aiming to show.

Answer (score 7):

There is a way to do it, but it does require a tiny bit of Galois theory.

1. Find a primitive element $\alpha$ for the whole extension.
2. Find its minimal polyomial $f$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ and all of its roots.
3. Find all factors of $f$ that are multiples of $x - \alpha$.
4. Now all subfields are obtained by extending $\mathbb{Q}$ with the coefficients of one of the polynomials in the previous step.

The rationale is that if $F$ is an intermediate field, and $g = a_{0} + a_{1} x + \dots + x^k$ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $F$, then $g$ divides $f$, and $F = \mathbb{Q}(a_0, a_{1}, \dots)$.

The *tiny bit* is in step 2, because you will be (implicitly, perhaps) using elements of the Galois group to get all the roots.

**PS** By the way, the above is straight from the proof that a simple extension has a finite number of intermediate fields.

Comment: This absolutely works! I was a bit disappointed in myself for not having encountered this way of looking at it earlier. I foresee a few smart undergrads working on the logic later this Spring!