# Finding all Subfields

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I'm wondering if my thinking here is right. I want to find all subfields of $\mathbb{Q}$($\sqrt2,\sqrt3)$. I believe that $\mathbb{Q}$($\sqrt2,\sqrt3)$ is the smallest field containing $\mathbb{Q}$, $\sqrt3$, and $\sqrt2$.

So this leads me to believe all of the subfields are: $\mathbb{Q}$($\sqrt2,\sqrt3)$ (the field itself), $\mathbb{Q}$($\sqrt2)$,$\mathbb{Q}$($\sqrt3)$, and $\mathbb{Q}$. Is this right?

Comment: Those are indeed subfields. There is one more, but it's a bit better hidden.

Comment: Another duplicate is [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/477275/find-all-intermediate-fields-of-extension-mathbbq-sqrt2-sqrt3-ma?rq=1).